# Basic Authentication logout issue in Hangfire Dashboard

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, hangfire

I have implemented **Hangfire** in an **ASP.NET Core 5** application. For authentication I am using below package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire.Dashboard.Basic.Authentication

After implementing authentication functionality for hangfire dashboard when I run the app and browse to hangfire dashboard link and insert correct input values, hangfire dashboard page is displaying properly.

However, I am unable to handle authentication logout functionality in hangfire dashboard.

I am providing sample to my code below:

### appsettings.json

```
{
    "HangfireConfiguration":
    {
        "UserName": "admin",
        "Password": "admin123"
    }
}
```

---

### Startup.cs:

```
using HangfireBasicAuthenticationFilter;

namespace Hangfire
{
    public IConfiguration _configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ......

        services.AddHangfire(config => config
            .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
            .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
            .UseDefaultTypeSerializer()                             
            .UseSqlServerStorage(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContext"), new SqlServerStorageOptions
            {
                CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                UsePageLocksOnDequeue = true,
                DisableGlobalLocks = true
            }));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ...)
    {
        var hangfireDashbaordOptions = new DashboardOptions
        {
            IgnoreAntiforgeryToken = true,
            AppPath = null,
            DashboardTitle = "Hangfire Dashboard",
            Authorization = new[]
            {
                new HangfireCustomBasicAuthenticationFilter
                {
                    User = _configuration.GetValue<string>("HangfireConfiguration:UserName"),
                    Pass = _configuration.GetValue<string>("HangfireConfiguration:Password")
                }
            }
        };

        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", hangfireDashbaordOptions);

        var hangfireServerOptions = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
        {
            WorkerCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2,
            HeartbeatInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
            ServerCheckInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
            SchedulePollingInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)
        };

        app.UseHangfireServer(hangfireServerOptions);

        ......
    }
}
```

---

How to handle authentication logout from hangfire dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

**O seguinte deve funcionar**.

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "HangfireConfiguration":
    {
        "UserName": "admin",
        "Password": "admin123",
        "AppPath": "https://logout:password@ENDERECO_DE_SUA_API/hangfire"
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
...
var hangfireDashbaordOptions = new DashboardOptions
        {
            IgnoreAntiforgeryToken = true,
            AppPath = _configuration.GetValue<string>("HangfireConfiguration:AppPath"),
            DashboardTitle = "Hangfire Dashboard",
            Authorization = new[]
            {
                new HangfireCustomBasicAuthenticationFilter
                {
                    User = _configuration.GetValue<string>("HangfireConfiguration:UserName"),
                    Pass = _configuration.GetValue<string>("HangfireConfiguration:Password")
                }
            }
        };
...
```

Desta forma quando o usuário clicar em voltar no painel ele será desconectado e precisará fornecer novamente as credenciais.